# Send email for open issues ( Send mail based on the text in another cell)

Tags: google-apps-script

I m using at google sheet to track the open issues by several departments.
I am trying to make a simple code for sending an email for the open issue to the responsible person.

Its not running correctly and showing frequent errors. can you pls help to correct this code.?

Google sheet link -  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sHTfshkLE609ISx0RosuQAYP_OZvOqFqZVLsa28BVkM/edit#gid=0

I am using below code for this.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1"); //get the sheet "Sheet1"
  var data = sSheet.getRange(5,1, sSheet.getLastRow(), sSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); //get the values of your table, without the header
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++); 
    var sendTO = e.values[3];
    var status = data[i];
    var subject = "test";
    var message = "this is test";
    if(status='Open') { 
        MailApp.sendEmail(sendTO,subject, message)
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the errors you are receiving? Moreover, the sheet you shared is not accessible - can you update the permissions for it? Also, does the `sendEmails` function have a trigger attached to it?

Comment: Hi.. I just update the permission for your access. Its showing me error  ".e is not defined (line 7, file "Code") and triggers not yet set for this script I want to have a daily trilggers for this reminder e-mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your code:

- you are using the `getSheetByName` with `sheet1` when the name of your actual sheet is `Sheet1`;
- you are using `e.values` but you haven't defined `e` anywhere in your code;
- you are defining the status as being `data[i]` but this will yield you the row with all the information, and not just the cell corresponding to the `status` column;

Therefore, I suggest you try the following snippet:

#### Snippet

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //get the sheet "Sheet1"
  var emails = sSheet.getRange(2,3, sSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
    var subject = sSheet.getRange(i+2,2).getValue();
    var message = "this is test";
    var status = sSheet.getRange(i+2,5).getValue();
    console.log(emails[i]);
    if (status == "Open") {
     MailApp.sendEmail(emails[i].toString(),subject, message)
    }
  } 
}
```

#### Explanation

There is no need to retrieve all the columns with all the data, so in this case, only the `Emails` column has been retrieved. Since your sheet has a header row, in order to retrieve the correct values, the `getLastRow()-1` has been used. Moreover, since when calling sheet methods, the indexes start at 1, in order to call the appropriate range `i+2` has been used (+1 for the sheet index and +1 for the header row). Afterwards, if the corresponding status is "Open", an email is sent.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns);
- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow).